# Why is prepayments and receivables recorded as one item in BABA's balance sheet?

Tags: accounting

I'm reading the fillings of BABA, https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1577552/000110465924011604/tm245446d1_ex99-1.htm

I noted something unusual in the balance sheet, the Prepayments and Receivables are recorded as a single item.

[image]

My questions

1. Why is alibaba recording them as a single item? Does it violate the GAAP standard?
2. I couldn't find the value of Receivables, but yahoo seems to be able to extract it, does anyone know how it's done? https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/baba/balance-sheet

Answer (score 1):

> Why is alibaba recording them as a single item?  Does it violate the GAAP standard?

GAAP standards do not focus on exactly how accounts are bucketed in the financial statement, so long as they are represented accurately (among other standards).

Companies can choose to consolidate items in whatever way they see fit so long as it provides sufficient transparency to their investors and shareholders. If reporting receivables as a standalone item were material and important to understand their performance, they would do so.

> I couldn't find the value of Receivables, but yahoo seems to be able to extract it, does anyone know how it's done?

Alibaba provides more details in the [annual report posted](https://www.alibabagroup.com/en-US/ir-financial-reports-financial-results) on [their IR portal](https://www.alibabagroup.com/en-US/ir-financial-reports-financial-results). I can find some of the items that Yahoo reports in the notes to their financial statements.

Most likely, Yahoo gets the raw data files from Edgar (which have more detail) instead of using the data from formatted reports.

Comment: I downloaded `FY 2024 Interim Report` from the portal, then I tried to look for keyword `receivables`, and I didn't find the note you mentioned. The only thing I found is `restricted cash` and the `prepayments` item. Am I looking into the wrong place?

Comment: I was looking at the 2023 report. There wasn't one line item that totaled receivables, but it did have at least some of the parts that Yahoo reported  (e.g. Tax receivables from page 339).